# save all the HTTP objects including header info in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I have downloaded the source code and compiled it on my linux machine(as instructed on the website). I want to intercept it on the point where I can save/copy(in some other directory) the HTTP/or whatever objects my browser receives from the internet.

I don't want to use network tools because of encryption and other issues. So I was thinking to use some open source browser and intercepting it.

So where should I exactly look into chromium code to get this job done.

Thanks

Comment: You may not need to modify the browser for that. Take a look at the [Remote debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) and it's [network tracking](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/network) capabilities.

Comment: Hi, It seems to be something, Can you please tell me a quick way to check this? like Network.responseReceived how I can use this?

Comment: No, I can't - haven't actually used it myself. But do note that Debugger protocol can replicate what Dev Tools display - see if it's enough for your purpose.